# Masking an image with an existing SVG path

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, mask

I have a set of SVG paths which make up a logo.

Then, I want to have several images (to appear as the SVG) which slide through gradually. My problem is that I cannot make them work as the background, in other words, I want the SVG to mask the image(s).

I have a SVG like this:

```html
<svg class="polygon" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="225.533px" height="261.262px" viewBox="0 0 225.533 261.262" style="enable-background:new 0 0 225.533 261.262;" xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="svg-draw">
    <path data-name="nav-projects" data-href="<?php print JUri::base() ?>projects" data-ajax="true" class=" st4 hover-logo" d="M26.05,147.366c-4.384,10.375-21.823,47.717-24.713,71.831c-2.804,23.373,2.034,40.255,27.625,37.926c6.952-0.97,15.662-4.346,24.417-9.214"></path>
  </g>
  <image clip-path="url(#svg-draw)" height="100%" width="100%"  xlink:href="<?php print THEME_URL."/img/rev1.jpg"; ?>" />
</svg>
```

And if you notice, I have put the `image` tag right inside the SVG. But nothing happens. I also have removed most of the Paths of the svg in the above example, because they are too long to be copied here.

I used the `clip-path` property of the image, but to no avail.

Comment: If you want SVG to be a background image it must be complete in a single file. You'd need to convert any image elements to use data URLs.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you please elaborate more? I want the SVG to mask off the image, so the image act somehow as the background of the SVG.

Comment: I can't really elaborate more because your question is unclear and I'm guessing at what's going on and what you want which is why I've written a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: More clear than this? I have an SVG logo consisting of several paths. I want to have an image as the background of the SVG logo.

Comment: If you want an image as the background, it should be the first item in the file. How are you displaying the SVG logo?

Comment: It is right inside of the HTML structure. It is NOT read from a file. And the structure is in the example. Just a number of paths are removed.

Comment: It should work then. Create a [mcve] if you want more help.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just clip with any element. You have to define a `<clipPath>` and clip with that.

```html
<svg class="polygon" version="1.1" id="Layer_1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="225.533px" height="261.262px"
     viewBox="0 0 225.533 261.262">

  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svg-draw">
      <path d="M26.05,147.366c-4.384,10.375-21.823,47.717-24.713,71.831
               c-2.804,23.373,2.034,40.255,27.625,37.926
               c6.952-0.97,15.662-4.346,24.417-9.214"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <image clip-path="url(#svg-draw)" height="100%" width="100%"
         xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the effect you wish to achieve, this CSS Tricks article should provide you with the right guidance https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/